# pygame, How do I make the score in my game add only once while inside the loop?

Tags: python, pygame

I am almost finished getting the core mechanics of my flappy bird clone almost done, except I'm not sure how to add the score once, the problem is its in the loop so when player collides with object/invisible wall it actually collides multiple times and adds more then one to the score, so my question is how would I make it only collide once and also add once to the score.

```
import sys
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Slivering snake")
window = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
black = 0, 0, 0
red = 255, 0, 0
score = 0
font = pygame.font.SysFont("segoe ui", 34, True)


class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, ):
        self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height = x, y, w, h
        self.colour = 0, 0, 255
        self.force = 12.5
        self.timer = 0

    def movement(self):
        self.keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if self.keys[pygame.K_w] or self.keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.force -= 0.2
            self.y -= self.force

    def gravity(self):
        self.y += 4

        self.timer += 1
        if self.timer >= 32:
            self.timer = 0
            self.force = 12.5

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.colour, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))


player = Player(60, 200, 50, 50)


class Pipes:
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, s):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.width, self.height = w, h
        self.speed = s
        self.colour = 0, 255, 0
        self.x1, self.y1 = 1450, 0

    def movement(self):
        self.x -= self.speed
        if self.x < -95:
            self.x = 1030
            location = random.randint(-300, 300)
            self.y = location

        self.x1 -= self.speed
        if self.x1 < -95:
            self.x1 = 1030
            location = random.randint(-300, 300)
            self.y1 = location

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.colour, (self.x, self.y - 300, self.width, self.height))
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.colour, (self.x, self.y + 490, self.width, self.height))
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.colour, (self.x1, self.y1 - 300, self.width, self.height))
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.colour, (self.x1, self.y1 + 490, self.width, self.height))


pipes = Pipes(900, 0, 70, 600, 3.5)

running = True
while running:
    window.fill(black)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    pipe_list = [
        pygame.Rect(pipes.x, pipes.y - 300, pipes.width, pipes.height),
        pygame.Rect(pipes.x, pipes.y + 490, pipes.width, pipes.height),
        pygame.Rect(pipes.x1, pipes.y1 - 300, pipes.width, pipes.height),
        pygame.Rect(pipes.x1, pipes.y1 + 490, pipes.width, pipes.height)
    ]
    score_rect = [
        pygame.Rect(pipes.x, 0, 1, 1024),
        pygame.Rect(pipes.x1, 0, 1, 1024)
    ]

    player.gravity()
    player.movement()
    pipes.movement()
    player_rect = pygame.Rect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height)
    for collision in pipe_list:
        if player_rect.colliderect(collision):
            running = False
    for points in score_rect:
        if player_rect.colliderect(points):
            score = score + 1

    text = font.render("Score " + str(score), True, red)
    print(score)
    pipes.draw()
    player.draw()
    window.blit(text, (30, 20))
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Pipes` object should not contain 2 or even more pipes, it contains just 1 pipe and has a state if the pipe has been passed (`self.passed`)

```py
class Pipes:
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, s):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.width, self.height = w, h
        self.speed = s
        self.colour = 0, 255, 0
        self.passed = False
```

When the pipe is recreated at the beginning, then the state pass has to be reset:

```py
class Pipes:
    # [...]

    def movement(self):
        self.x -= self.speed
        if self.x < -95:
            self.x = 1030
            location = random.randint(-300, 300)
            self.y = location
            self.passed = False
```

The class has a method `score`, which evaluates if the object is passed and returns true at the moment when the pipe is passed:

```py
class Pipes:
    # [...] 

    def score(self, player_rect):
        if not self.passed  and player_rect.colliderect(pygame.Rect(self.x, 0, 1, 1024)):
            self.passed = True
            return True
        return False
```

Further more, there is a method which evaluates if a player collides with the pipe:

````py
```py
class Pipes:
    # [...] 

    def collide(self, player_rect):
        rect1 = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y - 300, self.width, self.height)
        rect2 = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y + 490, self.width, self.height)
        return player_rect.colliderect(rect1) or player_rect.colliderect(rect2)
````

Create a list of 2 pipes

```py
pipe_list = [
    Pipes(900, 0, 70, 600, 3.5), 
    Pipes(1450, 0, 70, 600, 3.5)]
```

Move, draw, dot the collision test and evaluate the score in loops:

```py
while running:
    # [...]

    for pipe in pipe_list:
        pipe.movement()
    player_rect = pygame.Rect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height)
    for pipe in pipe_list:
        if pipe.collide(player_rect):
            running = False
    for pipe in pipe_list:
        if  pipe.score(player_rect):
            score += 1

    # [...]    

    for pipe in pipe_list:
        pipe.draw()
```

See the example:

```py
import sys
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Slivering snake")
window = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
black = 0, 0, 0
red = 255, 0, 0
score = 0
font = pygame.font.SysFont("segoe ui", 34, True)


class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, ):
        self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height = x, y, w, h
        self.colour = 0, 0, 255
        self.force = 12.5
        self.timer = 0

    def movement(self):
        self.keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if self.keys[pygame.K_w] or self.keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.force -= 0.2
            self.y -= self.force

    def gravity(self):
        self.y += 4

        self.timer += 1
        if self.timer >= 32:
            self.timer = 0
            self.force = 12.5

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.colour, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))


player = Player(60, 200, 50, 50)


class Pipes:
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, s):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.width, self.height = w, h
        self.speed = s
        self.colour = 0, 255, 0
        self.passed = False

    def movement(self):
        self.x -= self.speed
        if self.x < -95:
            self.x = 1030
            location = random.randint(-300, 300)
            self.y = location
            self.passed = False

    def score(self, player_rect):
        if not self.passed  and player_rect.colliderect(pygame.Rect(self.x, 0, 1, 1024)):
            self.passed = True
            return True
        return False

    def collide(self, player_rect):
        rect1 = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y - 300, self.width, self.height)
        rect2 = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y + 490, self.width, self.height)
        return player_rect.colliderect(rect1) or player_rect.colliderect(rect2)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.colour, (self.x, self.y - 300, self.width, self.height))
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.colour, (self.x, self.y + 490, self.width, self.height))


pipe_list = [
    Pipes(900, 0, 70, 600, 3.5), 
    Pipes(1450, 0, 70, 600, 3.5)]

running = True
while running:
    window.fill(black)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    player.gravity()
    player.movement()

    for pipe in pipe_list:
        pipe.movement()
    player_rect = pygame.Rect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height)
    for pipe in pipe_list:
        if pipe.collide(player_rect):
            running = False
    for pipe in pipe_list:
        if  pipe.score(player_rect):
            score += 1

    text = font.render("Score " + str(score), True, red)
    print(score)
    for pipe in pipe_list:
        pipe.draw()

    player.draw()
    window.blit(text, (30, 20))
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: could you explain to me why this turns True even though I don't see where it turns True at if not self.passed ----  `def score(self, player_rect):
        if not self.passed and player_rect.colliderect(pygame.Rect(self.x, 0, 1, 1024)):
            self.passed = True
            return True
        return False`